# Appropriate use of Javascript's bind()

Tags: javascript, this

I have had a look at JavaScript's bind method and I'm not sure in which kind of situations I should be using it. Would the following example of getting a random card from a deck (array) of cards be considered an appropriate use of the method:

```
function getRandomElementFromArray () {
    return this.splice( Math.floor( Math.random() * this.length ) )[0];
}

var deckOfCards = // Array of 52 cards;

var getRandomCard = getRandomElementFromArray.bind(deckOfCards);
```

Comment: You can’t say what’s appropriate and what’s inappropriate. This completely depends on what programming practices you follow, how complex the program gets, what will happen to the `getRandomCard` variable....

Comment: OK I see your point, in hindsight this question seems stupid to me even from 10 minutes ago. Will flag it for close. Edit: nvm I don't have the privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that's an appropriate use - the deck should be simply passed as a parameter.

The most common uses of `.bind` are to specifically attach a given `this` *when it wouldn't otherwise be possible to pass it* and/or to create a version of a function where the initial arguments are fixed and extra parameters passed are then added on, e.g.

For the former:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.callback = function() { ... }
}

var myobj = new MyObject();
el.addEventListener("click", myobj.callback.bind(myobj));
```

[without the `.bind` call the callback wouldn't refer to `this` correctly]

For the latter:

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b }
var add2 = add.bind(null, 2);   // no "this" needed in this case
add2(3);                        // returns 5
```

Comment: I’m down voting all answers as they shouldn’t be on Stack Overflow. Personally I agree with you, but this Q&A doesn’t fit Stack Overflow. By answering it you encourage further questions like this.

Comment: That's not (AFAIK) an appropriate reason - down vote the question by all means

Comment: Probably you want to check out meta – everybody is free to vote on his belief. Of course I’ve down voted the question and voted to close.

Comment: @idmean - I did - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: Did you read the last sentence in that link? If you argument like this, did you read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions?

Answer (score 0):

No. It should only be used in OOP when you have an object and you need to pass one method from its `prototype` to another function. In other cases it generally just doesn't make sense.

```
function  MyClass() {
  this.name = 'foo';
}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() { return this.name; }

var myObj = new MyClass();
// say we need to pass myObj.myMethod somewhere else

var func = myObj.myMethod;
func(); // undefined -- doesn't work.

var func2 = myObj.myMethod.bind(myObj);
func2(); // 'foo' -- works!
```

Comment: There's plenty of uses for `.bind` outside of OOP

Comment: yeah that'd mostly be with currying as `this` is rarely used outside OOP. anyway OP was asking about using bind with `this` and I didn't want to overcomplicate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about "appropriate" you have to be a bit more specific. I think it is save to say, that your question can be answered by looking into some styleguides oder conventions. I have looked up one that explains it pretty much self speeking:

> One of the deficiencies in Javascript is that callback functions are not bound to the correct or expected context (as referenced with the this variable). In ES2015, this problem is solved by using so-called arrow functions for callbacks.
>
> However, while we're still writing ES5 code, we can use the .bind
> method to bind the correct this context to the callback method.
>
> For example:

```
this.$el = $("#some-element");
setTimeout(function () {
    // Without using .bind, "this" will refer to the window object.
    this.$el.hide();
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

This is a styleguide written by Plone ( a content management system ) who may look at this problem from a perspective different then google or other companies. That's why you have to decide if it is "appropriate" in your context.

Link to the Styleguide: [Plone Styleguide](http://docs.plone.org/develop/styleguide/javascript.html)